# Using same folder named typescript file as default files in VS Code

Tags: typescript

I'm using the npm package 'directory-named-webpack-plugin' to make it so my default files are named after the folder in which they are contained, instead of having hundreds of index.ts tabs in VS Code, and in my console output/debugger. It works great. Everything builds in both nextjs and storybook.

But VS Code can't seem to resolve the import statements. Is there a way to configure either typescript through tsconfig.json or throughs some other method in VS Code directly?

Comment: Great question! Did you figure out a good solution?

Comment: Nope. Never did.

Answer (score 0):

There is information [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node) on how you could do that, assuming that you are using `commonjs` module resolution (which I believe is the default).

Suppose I have the following directory structure + files:

```
src
|
+- my-module
|  |
|  + my-module.ts
|
+- index.ts
```

and in `index.ts` I want to  import `my-module` like so:

```
import myModule from './my-module'
```

To make `my-module.ts` recognized as the `index` file, create `src/my-module/package.json` with the following:

```
{ "main": "my-module.ts" }
```

and restart the TS server.

Of course, now you've got thousands of `package.json` files instead of `index.ts`, but I can't see another way around this.

Comment: That's probably too much overhead. I'd rather just use index.ts at that point.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to write a webpack plugin to add those package.json files in memory at build time? hmmm...

Comment: You could auto-generate the `package.json` files with a nodejs script which uses the [File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) package. It could navigate to each directory and write/overwrite `package.json` to include the name of the directory. That way, the only thing you'd need to do whenever you add a new directory would be to run the script e.g. `node scripts/generate-package-jsons.js`.